# C++ Metaprogramming: Generating a byte sequence based on type/value input?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, metaprogramming, c++17

So this might be one of those "that's obviously easy" or "obviously impossible" questions..

But imagine a simple buffer protocol where the data is prefixed by a byte indicating the type. So you'd have `04 00` for a false bool and `02 00 00 00 01` for a uint32_t with a value of 1.

Would it be possible to serialize data at compiletime so that `Serialize(false, true, uint32_t(3));` returns a sequence like `04 00 04 01 02 00 00 00 03`?

If so, could one create prepared statements like that would just have zeroes in the sequence that could be filled at runtime? As well as maybe even doing basic unit-testing like `static_assert(Deserialize<bool, bool>("\x04\x01\x04\x00")[0] == true, "Error");`

```
// e.g something like this.
template<typename T> constexpr uint8_t Prefix()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>) return 0x04;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, uint32_t>) return 0x02;
    return 0x00;
};
template <typename T> ctString Write(T Value)
{
    ctString Temp{};
    Temp += Write(Prefix<T>());
    Temp += /* something sizeof(Value) */;
    return Temp;
};
template <typename... Args> ctString Serialize(std::tuple<Args...> Input)
{
    ctString Temp{};
    std::apply([&](auto Argument) { Temp += Write(Argument); }, Input);
    return Temp;
};

constexpr auto Message = Serialize(false, true, uint32_t(3));
```

Comment: C++11, C++14 or C++17? If you can use C++17, I see a solution a lot simpler.

Comment: @max66: As OP uses `if constexpr`, c++17 seems fine.

Comment: @Jarod42 - D'Oh! You're right. Stupid question.

Comment: Have you succeed to write it without meta-prog ? which part do you fail to turn compile time ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Runtime is fairly straight-forward. Just use a container like std::string and append a byte then the data. Similarly, I can set up a Deserialize function that returns a tuple that's filled at runtime. Doing it at compiletime is harder though.

Comment: So instead of `std::string`, try to use `std::array<char, N>` (kind of compile-time string): you can compute `N` at compile time depending of the type.

Comment: @max66 

1. Was more of a random thought, like creating a struct like `struct { union { struct {char Type1; bool v1; char Type2; uint32_t v2;}, char Raw[7]; } }` that could be initialized with just the type bytes set so one could just assign and memcpy the whole message.

2. Deserialize in this case would return a tuple of type <bool, bool>. Guess std::get<0> would have been more proper.

Comment: @Jarod42 How would one chain the sizes together though? As in, `for (i = 0; sizeof...(args)) Count += sizeof(arg[i]); std::array<char, Count>;`

Comment: Something like `constexpr std::size_t total_size = (computeSize<Args>() + ...);`,  in your case, `computeSize<Args>()` seems to be `(1 + sizeof(Args))`.

Comment: I see... so you have to explicit `<bool, bool>` because the returned types cannot depends form `"\x04\x01\x04\x00"` because the returned type of the function cannot depends from the value of the function argument. Another question: It's necessary thar `Serialize()` and `Deserialize()` works also run-time or you can use something that works only compile-time?

Comment: @max66 I do currently have a version that works at runtime, but I've noticed that 8/10 of the messages that I return could have been generated at compiletime. So a separate implementation could indeed work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto serialize(Args... args) {
    // better not pass in std::string or something...
    static_assert((std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Args> && ...));

    // each size better fit in a byte
    static_assert((sizeof(Args) < 256 && ...));

    std::array<char, 
       (sizeof...(Args) +    // one byte for each arg
       (sizeof(Args) + ...)  // sum of the sizes of the args
       )> buffer;
    char* p = buffer.data();
    auto fill = [](char* p, auto arg) { /* ... */ };
    (p = fill(p, args), ...);
    return buffer;
}
```

The tricky part is writing `fill` such that you can actually implement it in `constexpr` - since you can't use either `memcpy` or placement new to write the arg into the buffer. You have to manually do things - which means you have to manually manage endianness and all that junk. The simple direction is:

```
auto fill = [](char* p, auto arg) {
    *p++ = sizeof(arg);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arg); ++i) {
        *p++ = arg & 0xff;
        arg >>= 8;
    }
    return p;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I propose a template-meta-programming version that works compile-time *only* and store the serialization in a `std::integer_sequence<char, ...>` type (intead of `char` you can use `unsigned char` or `std::uint8_t` or other type, obviously).

So the serialization is done passing the values that you want serialize as template arguments obtaining a type (this works only starting from C++17 because use `auto` template value types)

```
using t1 = Serialize_t<false, true, std::uint32_t{3u}>;
```

and deserialization return a `constexpr std::tuple<Ts...>` (where `Ts...` are the appropriate types)

```
// d, in this case, is a std::tuple<bool, bool, std::uint32_t>
constexpr auto d { Deserialize_v<t1> }; 

static_assert( std::get<0>(d) == false             );
static_assert( std::get<1>(d) == true              );
static_assert( std::get<2>(d) == std::uint32_t{3u} );
```

The following is a full compiling (C++17) example

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <int I, auto V, char ... Cs>
struct IntChs : public IntChs<I-1, (V >> 8), char(V & 0xff), Cs...>
 { };

template <auto V, char ... Cs>
struct IntChs<0, V, Cs...>
 { using type = std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>; };

template <int I, auto V>
using IntChs_t = typename IntChs<I, V>::type;

template <typename, char ...>
struct ConcatChs;

template <char ... Cs0, char ... Cs1>
struct ConcatChs<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs0...>, Cs1...>
 { using type = std::integer_sequence<char, Cs1..., Cs0...>; };

template <typename T, T V, char ... Cs>
struct SerVal;

// std::uint32_t case
template <std::uint32_t V, char ... Cs>
struct SerVal<std::uint32_t, V, Cs...>
  : public ConcatChs<IntChs_t<4, V>, Cs..., '\x02'>
 { };

// bool case
template <bool V, char ... Cs>
struct SerVal<bool, V, Cs...>
  : public ConcatChs<IntChs_t<1, int(V)>, Cs..., '\x04'>
 { };    

// ******************************** //
// other serialization cases to add //
// ******************************** //

template <auto V, char ... Cs>
struct ConcatSer : public SerVal<decltype(V), V, Cs...>
 { };

template <auto V, char ... Cs>
using ConcatSer_t = typename ConcatSer<V, Cs...>::type;

template <typename, auto ...>
struct Serialize;

template <char ... Cs, auto V0, auto ... Vs>
struct Serialize<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>, V0, Vs...>
 : public Serialize<ConcatSer_t<V0, Cs...>, Vs...>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct Serialize<T>
 { using type = T; };

template <auto ... Vs>
using Serialize_t = typename Serialize<std::integer_sequence<char>, Vs...>::type;

template <typename T, char ... Cs>
constexpr T Val ()
 {
   T ret{};

   ((ret <<= 8, ret += T(Cs)), ...);

   return ret;
 }

template <typename, auto...>
struct Deserialize;

// bool case
template <char C0, char ... Cs, auto ... Vs>
struct Deserialize<std::integer_sequence<char, '\x04', C0, Cs...>, Vs...>
   : public Deserialize<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>,
                        Vs..., Val<bool, C0>()>
 { };

// std::uint32_t case
template <char C0, char C1, char C2, char C3, char ... Cs, auto ... Vs>
struct Deserialize<std::integer_sequence<char, '\x02', C0, C1, C2, C3, Cs...>,
                   Vs...>
   : public Deserialize<std::integer_sequence<char, Cs...>,
                        Vs..., Val<std::uint32_t, C0, C1, C2, C3>()>
 { };

// ********************************** //
// other deserialization cases to add //
// ********************************** //

// final case: the tuple
template <auto ... Vs>
struct Deserialize<std::integer_sequence<char>, Vs...>
 { static constexpr auto value = std::make_tuple(Vs...); };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Deserialize_v = Deserialize<T>::value;

int main()
 {
   using t1 = Serialize_t<false, true, std::uint32_t{3u}>;
   using t2 = std::integer_sequence<char, 
      '\x04', '\x00', '\x04', '\x01', '\x02', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x03'>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<t1, t2> );

   constexpr auto d { Deserialize_v<t1> }; 

   static_assert( std::get<0>(d) == false             );
   static_assert( std::get<1>(d) == true              );
   static_assert( std::get<2>(d) == std::uint32_t{3u} );
 }
```

This code works for big-endian and little-endian architectures but with a great limit: require that the number of bits in a `char` is 8.